# Load page on selection from dropdown form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am trying to make a drop down menu that takes me to various webpages.  Right now it is set up so you make your selection and then you hit a "Go" button and then it takes you to the appropriate link.  I am trying to figure out how to make it so when you make your selection it automatically goes and you don't need to push the "Go" button.

Here is what I have:

```
<p align="center">
<form name="jump" class="center">
<select name="menu">
<option value="#">Select an option</option>
<option value="/link1.shtml">Link 1</option>
<option value="/link2.shtml">Link 2</option>
<option value="/link3.shtml">Link 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
</form>
</p>
```

Any help or links to explanations would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: is there a way to provide your original javascript? I'm working on the exact same thing. I have a dropdown with cities. The user selects city and then has to click the 'Go' button to move to another webpage or website (depends on the selection). I'm not familiar with javascipt so it would be amazing if you can share.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="http://www.apple.com/">Apple</option>
    <option value="http://www.bbc.com">BBC</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
</select>​
```

What you were looking for was 'onchange' instead of 'onsubmit'

Answer (score 2):

Check out [jQuery .change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
<script>
   $('select.menu').change(function(e){
      // this function runs when a user selects an option from a <select> element
      window.location.href = $("select.menu option:selected").attr('value');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help - basically you just tie an onChange event to the select so that when a new option is selected it'll forward the location to the page.

```
<p align="center">
<form name="jump" class="center">
<select name="menu" onchange="gotoPage(this)">
<option value="#">Select an option</option>
<option value="/link1.shtml">Link 1</option>
<option value="/link2.shtml">Link 2</option>
<option value="/link3.shtml">Link 3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onClick="location=document.jump.menu.options[document.jump.menu.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
</form>
</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function gotoPage(select){
    window.location = select.value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you start using the javascript framework [jQuery](http://jquery.org) as it really will make your life much easier when it comes to javascript.

When you have jQuery installed and setup in you web page you should be able to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selection").change(function() {
            location = $("#selection option:selected").val();
        });
    });
</script>

<p align="center">
    <form name="jump" class="center">
        <select name="menu" id="selection>
            <option value="#">Select an option</option>
            <option value="/link1.shtml">Link 1</option>
            <option value="/link2.shtml">Link 2</option>
            <option value="/link3.shtml">Link 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously super late to the party here, but since I was trying to figure out the same thing and was able to, I'll post how here.

The other answers have you load the link when you change your select element option, but you originally had asked to do it with a button, after making your selection. This worked for me:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var newUrl = "";
        $("#picksite").change(function() {
            $newUrl = $("#picksite option:selected").val();
        });
        $("#executelink").click(function() {
            location = $newUrl ;
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="picksite">
    <option value="">Pick A Website</option>
    <option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://facebook.com">Facebook</option>
    <option value="http://twitter.com">Twitter</option>
    <option value="http://gmail.com">Gmail</option>
</select>

<button id="executelink">Go To Site</button>
```