# When clicking/choosing an option a link specified to that option will proceed

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Hello everyone! I just want to ask, when I choose regular in my drop down. The link goes to the regular.html as well as the contractual. How can I do it? Thank you in advance. :)]

Also here's my code for the regular.html:
regular.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop down</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Regular</h1>
    <select>
        <option href="regular.html">Regular</option>
        <option href="contractual.html">Contractual</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is for the contractual:
contractual.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drop down</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Contractual</h1>
    <select>
        <option href="regular.html">Regular</option>
        <option href="contractual.html">Contractual</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please refer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175445/load-page-on-selection-from-dropdown-form

Comment: What exactly you would like to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
    <select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="regular.html">Regular</option>
        <option value="contractual.html">Contractual</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. it worked perfectly. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var url = $('option:selected', this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: Load jquery `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` before the code

Comment: thank for your answer. I appreciate your effort. thank you again. :)

Comment: @FrancisVargas : why the reply will be down voted ?.

Comment: other user will down voted your answer, not me. sorry for that. :)