# Laravel pagination according to drop-down

Tags: php, laravel

How to paginate in `laravel` 5 by drop-down values?
I have tried as below.

```
public function getreport() {

        ->Paginate(10);

        $links = str_replace('/?', '?', $buildings->render());

        return view('daily_entry_report',compact('buildings'));
    }
```

Here buildings refer to my database query.

Comment: Is your question really just `how to add where clause to pagination`?

Comment: i want to paginate my view page according to drop-down values which are 5,10,15 entries per page

Comment: in the above it paginates 10 pages,but i want the user to select the drop-down values.

Comment: Simple solution is to have dynamic value for `paginate()` as `paginate(Input::get('number'))` where number you send from frontend

Comment: <form action="/getreport">
<select name="number">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: this was my view file.

Comment: public function getreport(Request $request) {

   
      
   $school = DB::table('school')
      
   ->Paginate((Input::get('number')));
   
   $links = str_replace('/?', '?', $buildings->render());
   
   return view('view',compact('school'))

Comment: it says input error

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter ($dropdownvalue) to the method and use it with paginate:

```
public function getreport($dropdownvalue = 10) {
     ->Paginate($dropdownvalue);
```

For this to work, you also have to edit the route (route/web.php) so that it takes the value (what does your route look like?):

```
Route::get('/getreport/{dropdownvalue}', ['as'=>'report.get', 'uses' => 'ReportController@getreport']);
```

In order to show 5 reports at a time, you can access:

> mydomaine.com/getreport/5

To use it with your dropdown, you need to "reload"/"redirect" the page after each selection. Simplest way would be to use javascript. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175445/load-page-on-selection-from-dropdown-form) to see how.

Note that this is not the best way to do this but it works.

Comment: public function getreport($dropdownvalue = 10) {

   
  
   
   $school = DB::table('school')
   -
   
   ->Paginate($dropdownvalue);
   
   $links = str_replace('/?', '?', $buildings->render());
   
   return view('view',compact('school');   my controller

Comment: on selecting the value it says page not found

Comment: <form method="get" action="/getreport/{dropdownvalue}">
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option>Please select</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
 
</select>​
</form>

Comment: What does your route look like? You can find it in routes/web.php
And what is the url when it says page not found?

Comment: $searchby = $request->get('number')  returning null value after passing dd($searchby)    where number is select name in view

Comment: I mean the route you use. You can find it in routes/web.php