# how do i add a link so that when i select an element in my dropdown menu i get redirected to thee page

Tags: php, laravel, forms, html.dropdownlistfor

Im trying to be able to be redirected to the page that the post is on when i select a post from a dropdown list of all my posts.

at the moment i have managed to populate the list with all of the post titles and i have added a link in the form of a  to each element in the list but when i click on one of the elements nothing happens.

here is the code i use to populate the list:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="post" name="post" required focus>
        @foreach($post as $posts)
            @if($posts->user_id == Auth::user()->id)
                <option value="/posts/{{$posts->id}}" selected>
                    <a href="/posts/{{$posts->id}}">
                        {{$posts->title}}
                    </a>
                </option>
             @endif       
         @endforeach
     </select> 
</div>
```

the page that i need to be redirected is in the following format:

```
/posts/id
```

where the id is the post id

How do i make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load page on selection from dropdown form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175445/load-page-on-selection-from-dropdown-form)

Comment: No, i tried that and it just messed everything up as in instead of there just being one list there is now one list for every element and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('')}}/posts/{{$posts->id}}">{{$posts->title}}</a>
```

Comment: Could possibly use `route()` instead of `url('')` no?

Comment: @Coola, You are right. But I don't know what is the route of his/her

Comment: i tried that but it still doesn't do anything

Comment: @es915 First you have to select one item. But I can see in your dropdown you select more than one item

Comment: @es915 You are most welcome to hear your problem has fixed

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just setting my option value as link/route I want to redirect, and put the onchange event. `onchange="window.location.href=this.value;"`

```
   <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="post" name="post" required focus onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
            @foreach($post as $posts)
              <option value="{{route('your-route', $posts->id)}}">{{$posts->title}}</option>      
            @endforeach
         </select> 
    </div>
```